# Lower the threshold for switching from integrated graphics to discrete graphics

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, gpu

I'm running linux mint cinnamon on a laptop which has both a intel CPU and nvidia GPU. There is an option to use Nvidia on demand for graphics. However, the system is too reluctant to switch to the Nvidia card so if the laptop is under moderate load then it can be quite laggy. Does anyone know of a way to lower the threshold for switching to the nvidia GPU